# How can I make my modal centered when adding a image to it?

Tags: javascript, css

It seems overtime I add a image to my modal, it gets off centered from the user page.

When I say off centered, I mean the modal will be more down while leaving space on top.

I made a JS fiddle so you can see for yourself (resize your browser to 1230x650 if you can't see it)
https://jsfiddle.net/2whfsnqe/

Image of the problem:
[image]

How can I make my modal center correctly when a image is added?

Js fiddle code:

```
<button onclick='noImage()'>
Open modal without image
</button>
<button onclick='withImage()'>
Open modal with image
</button>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
   <div id='modal-content' class="modal-content">
     <div id='modal-header' class="modal-header">
        <span id='close' class="close">&times;</span>
       <h2 id='modal-title'><!--- modal-title to set data !---></h2>        
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body"><!--- modal-body to set data !---></div>
     <div class="modal-footer" id="modal-footer"><!--- modal-footer to set data !---></div>
   </div>
 </div>
<script>
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
function noImage(){
  setModalTitle("HELLO!");
  setModalBody("<p>This modal has no image - and is centered fine.</p>");
  openModal();
}

function withImage(){
  setModalTitle("HELLO!");
  setModalBody("<p>This modal has a image, and isn't centered right :(</p><p>See how it goes off the page if you resize your browser to be smaller while leaving space on top?</p><img src='https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=250x250&cht=qr&chl=3G58sN2JVX3tLBBDKfuUZ9q3fmG3nZ53iY '>");
  openModal();
}

function openModal(){
    span.onclick = function() {
        closeModal();
    }
    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target === modal) {
            closeModal();
        }
    }
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

function closeModal(){
    modal.style.display = "none";
    setModalBody("");
    setModalTitle("");
}

function setModalTitle(text){
    document.getElementById("modal-title").innerHTML = text;
}

function setModalBody(html){
    document.getElementById("modal-body").innerHTML = html;
}
</script>
/* modals */
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 10%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 80%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: animatetop;
    animation-duration: 0.4s;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #000;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.modal-header {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;;
    color: black;
}

.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

.modal-footer {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The modal container has a `padding-top` value of 10%, and since padding percentages are based on the width of the container (see [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#padding-properties)), it's expanding along with the width.

To fix it, you could either change the padding to an absolute value, or use flexbox to align it in the centre of the window.